# Using cordova to set values in the android project.properties file

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services, cordova-plugins

#### TL;DR

I have a cordova app that is targeting both iOS and Android. Is there a way using `config.xml` to set the values inside the cordova generated file `platforms/android/project.properties`?

#### More details:

There is an issue using certain plugins that make use of google play services that prevents me from building the app:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
>   Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzo;

In my case it has to due with the fact that I'm using both the [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) and [google-analytics-plugin](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin) plugins in the same project.

One way to fix this is to edit the `platforms/android/project.properties` file to include which version of google play services to use:

```
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0
```

The issue is that of course everything under `platforms` is generated by cordova and is blown away on a regular basis, requiring us to continually replace the `platforms/android/project.properties` file.

Is there a way using `config.xml` to set the values inside the cordova generated file `platforms/android/project.properties`?

Comment: did you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

the good solution for me was using the **variable** tag like this:

```
<plugin name="pluginA" spec="npm">
  <variable name=”PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION” value="15.0.0" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="pluginB" spec="npm">
  <variable name=”PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION” value="15.0.0" />
</plugin>
```

[The source](https://blog.phonegap.com/the-play-services-problem-with-cordova-applications-489c9aeb2e89)